# Calculating The Potential Dimensions of an Effective Pipette

Tags: fluid-dynamics

Is there a formula for calculating the potential variable dimensions of a non-bulb pipette (using a finger to block air ingress) to ensure fluid is retained within the pipette. For example, as a template, assume a 66cm pipette, with 6mm ID, narrowing to 1mm at the point of discharge prevents leakage. Can these dimensions be varied to get the same favorable outcome, eg a 33cm pipette with 3mm ID, and 0.5mm p.o.discharge. And so on. And is there a formula for calculating these potential effective variables?

Comment: look up "similitude parameters" or "dimensionless groups". the one you want to use is one that relates gravity and surface tension (I cannot remember its name) but it allows you to choose a nozzle diameter which either prohibits or allows two-phase flow.

Comment: Thanks Niels. Single phase flow only. How does this sound. A formula for selecting nozzle size of pipe/pipette in relation variable lengths (and variable pipe dia?) having regard to gravity, surface tension, and ambient air pressure?

Comment: pretty complicated. easier to do experiments rather than trying to write out the differential equations. single biggest factor is surface tension of the liquid. Do you happen to know what it is? -NN

Comment: Surface tension is unknown. It is water - near enough. How does one calculate the force of gravity and the surface tension of water in a pipette say 66cm long, 6mm ID, and 1.5mm dia nozzle (which happens to work just fine). The objective is for the forces of surface tension (and ambient, external air pressure?) to exceed the force of gravity so that fluid is retained in a pipette until air exposure.  If there were a formula for this so I could calculate other more suitable size variables for the pipette. If not, it is trial and error.

Answer (score 0):

knowing the mass of water in the pipette, you then know the gravity head present at its tip when held vertically. in the young-laplace equation, equate this pressure to that generated by a mensicus of a certain radius of curvature assuming the surface tension for water. solve for the radius of curvature sufficient to oppose the gravity head. the criticality condition (pipette fails, liquid runs out) occurs when the tip diameter is equal to twice that radius of curvature i.e., when a hemispherical meniscus results.

Comment: Thanks niels. I am trying to absorb this. Does this mean the ID of the pipette is crucial, but the pipette length is irrelevant?

Comment: O, just realised the pipette length is a factor in the mass/gravity head, yes?

Comment: yes yes. both factors are crucial.